# Can we check if table in bigquery is in locked or DML operation is being performed

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a BQ table which has multiple data load/update/delete jobs scheduled in. Since this is automated jobs many of it are failing due to concurrent update issue. 
I need to know if we have a provision in BigQuery to check if the table is already locked by DML operation and can we serialize the queries so that no job fails

Comment: Can you please explain who is generating the error message and provide the excat error itself. Also add more details how the automatic is triggered

Comment: Update, delete and insert queries are automated using airflow. It throws below error:- Could not serialize access to table my_table due to concurrent update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the job ID generated by client code to keep track of the job status and only begin the next query when that job is done. [This](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#batch) describe that process.

Alternatively you could try [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#exp-backoff) to retry the query a certain amount of times to prevent automatic failure of the query due to locked tables.